# Fast computation of $\det(A^\top A)$ with $A$ lower triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, where $m \geq n$, be a lower triangular matrix, i.e. $A_{ij} = 0$ whenever $j > i$. I am interested in computing $\det(A^\top A)$ as efficiently as possible, and would rather avoid having to compute the product $A^\top A$. In the case where $m=n$, the problem simplifies as:

$$\det(A^\top A) = \det(A^\top) \det(A) = \det(A)^2 = \prod_{i=1}^n A_{ii}^2$$

Is there a similar simplification (or any other) for the case where $m > n$?

Thanks!

Comment: The singular values of $A$ can be computed without computing $A^TA$. You can easily compute the determinant of $A^TA$ based on the singular values of $A$.

Comment: $$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & d \\ 0 & c & e \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ b & c \\ d & e \end{array} \right]
= \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a^2 + b^2 + d^2 & bc+de \\ bc+de & c^2 + e^2 \end{array} \right]
$$
$$
a^2 c^2 + a^2 e^2 + b^2 c^2 + b^2 e^2 + d^2 c^2 + d^2 e^2 -b^2c^2 - d^2e^2 - 2bcde \\ {} \\
= a^2c^2 + a^2 e^2 + b^2 e^2 + d^2 c^2 -2bcde \\ {} \\
= a^2 (c^2+e^2) + (be-dc)^2
$$
The thing that leaps out at me from this is that one of the two terms is the determinant of the part that's below those $0$s. $\qquad$

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri while using singular values could be done, it is still computationally expensive and it does not improve upon the $O(mn^2 + n^3)$ needed to compute the product and then the determinant.

Comment: It would interest me greatly know which application requires this determinant and why. This information would be a valuable addition to your question. There are very few applications which require determinants and therefore little motivation to look for the answers you seek.

Comment: The [Cauchy Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) gives you
$$
\det(A^TA) = \sum_{S\in\tbinom{[n]}m} \det(A_{[m],S})^2.
$$